# Tyre loosing air pressure despite having no puncture

Tags: maintenance, tire, puncture, tire-pressure

The front tyre on my bike looses air pressure despite there being no punctures. There is no leak via the Schrader valve either. If I fill up the tyre, it looses a considerable amount of pressure by day 3. What could be causing this?

Comment: if a tyre is losing air, you either have a puncture or a faulty valve. There is no "third way".

Comment: What about the age of the inner tube? Or the quality. Some are porous from the factory. BTW: How did you check for punctures? If there's a slow leak you will probably not notice it when holding the tube in a water basin.

Comment: @PeteH Negative on both. I checked for punctures and faulty valves, and also took it to a local shop where I got it confirmed.

Comment: @Carel How do I check for slow leaks?

Comment: You can keep adding air and provides more pressure by squeezing the tube. It should be immersed in water bath

Comment: There are tubes (some quite expensive) that leak down rapidly because they're so thin.  But most likely you have a bad tube or valve.

Answer (score 0):

1. A puncture
2. The tire lining along the valve is faulty.
3. The seam in the tire is faulty somewhere around the tire.

The best way to find out is put some soap in a bucket/tray of water and cover the tire. Fill it up as much as you can and the bubbles are where the leak is!